# Netty 4 - Encoder not writing to following encoder

Tags: java, networking, netty

I currently have set up a networked client that makes use of two encoders, a single decoder, and a `ChannelInboundMessageHandlerAdapter<ByteBuf>`. The encoders are a `MessageToByteEncoder<Packet>` and a `ByteToByteEncoder`. I've tried using a `ChannelOutboundMessageHandlerAdapter` and a `ChannelOutboundByteHandlerAdapter` but neither of them remedied the problem. It enters the first encoder (`PacketEncoder` or the `MessageToByteEncoder<Packet>`) just fine, but fails to enter the `ByteToByteEncoder` afterword and no data is sent to the server.

My pipeline is set up like so:

```
ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();
// Decoders
pipeline.addLast("buffer_length_decoder", new BufferLengthDecoder());
pipeline.addLast("packet_decoder", new PacketDecoder());

// Encoder
pipeline.addLast("buffer_length_encoder", new BufferLengthEncoder());
pipeline.addLast("packet_encoder", new PacketEncoder());
```

PacketEncoder looks like so:

```
public class PacketEncoder extends MessageToByteEncoder<Packet> {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PacketEncoder.class);

    @Override
    protected void encode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Packet msg, ByteBuf out) throws Exception {
        ByteBuf buf = msg.buf();
        buf = buf.capacity(buf.readableBytes());
        logger.info(Utils.toHexString(buf.array()));
        out.writeBytes(buf);
    }
}
```

BufferLengthEncoder looks like so:

```
public class BufferLengthEncoder extends ByteToByteEncoder {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BufferLengthEncoder.class);

    @Override
    protected void encode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf in, ByteBuf out) throws Exception {
        logger.info(Utils.toHexString(in.array()));
        out = out.writeInt(in.readableBytes()).writeBytes(in);
    }
}
```

I have tried changing their order in the pipeline to no avail. I assume that I'm just missing something nonsensical somewhere, but I'm unsure where or what. Any and all help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You seem to be writing the number of bytes as a single byte, a value in the range 0, ..., 127, -128, ..., -1. Might something go wrong there? An overflow >= 128 or >= 256.

Comment: You're right, I did mean to change that, but the original message that I'm writing is but 6 bytes long. I've made changes now to reflect this issue. The problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds strange to me... could you please write a unit test that shows the problem and open an issue after you are sure it is a bug ?

https://github.com/netty/netty/issues